# Firebase: Retrieve nested data from unknown children

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase structure like this

```
"broadcast": {
    "ghjghjFc1S3KO0y8yJwORdfgret": {   //user ID
         "ryrtybgzMiI858YyGua": {  //broadcast ID
              "a": "xxx",   // broadcast Detail
              "b": "yyy",
              "c": false
         }
         "cbvbcvbMvAnSDqTb15vU": {  //broadcast ID
              "a": "xxx",   // broadcast Detail
              "b": "yyy",
              "c": true
         }
    }
    "3uqWZJRFc1S3KO0y8yJwORTMtWC2": {   //user ID
         "jkhjkbgzMiI858YyGua": {  //broadcast ID
              "a": "xxx",   // broadcast Detail
              "b": "yyy",
              "c": false
         }
         "qwwerqweMvAnSDqTb15vU": {  //broadcast ID
              "a": "xxx",   // broadcast Detail
              "b": "yyy",
              "c": true
         }
    }
}
```

I want to retrieve all nodes having broadcasts where c is equal to true. How can I do this in swift?

Comment: For all the users or single user?

Comment: @NiravD thanks. I have already tried this query but I got nothing ( snapshot.childrenCount = 0)

Comment: @user7814783 Actually I want to retrieve all the users along their broadcasts but only those users and broadcasts which have 'c' equals to true

Comment: do you know all the user uid's programatically?

Comment: @user7814783 no I don't know. I don't want to make another query to get IDs of all users. Is there any way to retrieve data from two unknown nested childs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could do this is by restructuring your database:

```
"userBroadcasts": {
    "ghjghjFc1S3KO0y8yJwORdfgret": { // user ID
        "ryrtybgzMiI858YyGua": true, // broadcastID
        "jkhjkbgzMiI858YyGua": true, // another broadcastID
        // etc..
    },
    // more users down here...
}

"broadcast": {
    "ryrtybgzMiI858YyGua": { // broadcast ID
        "a": "xxx",   // broadcast Detail
        "b": "yyy",
        "c": false
    },
    "jkhjkbgzMiI858YyGua": {
        "a": "xxx",
        "b": "yyy",
        "c": true
    },
    // more broadcasts down here...
}
```

Then you can get all the broadcasts you want by calling:

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("broadcast").queryOrdered(byChild: "c").queryEqual(toValue: true)
```

If you want the userID as well, store this inside the broadcast when you create it, for example:

```
"broadcast": {
    "ryrtybgzMiI858YyGua": { // broadcast ID
        "a": "xxx",   // broadcast Detail
        "b": "yyy",
        "c": false,
        "userID":"ghjghjFc1S3KO0y8yJwORdfgret"
    },
    "jkhjkbgzMiI858YyGua": {
        "a": "xxx",
        "b": "yyy",
        "c": true,
        "userID":"ghjghjFc1S3KO0y8yJwORdfgret"
    },
    // more broadcasts down here...
}
```

Embrace denormalisation with the Firebase Database!

Comment: Thanks Bradley. In this way I know it should work. Could you please guide me what would be the database structure if user can have multiple records of same broadcast ID but with different broadcast details ?

Comment: @WaqarAli That would require a much more complex structure. Are you sure you need a user to have 2 broadcasts of the same ID? An ID is usually supposed to uniquely identify an element.

Comment: Yes, in my case user can have multiple broadcasts with same Ids but with different details i.e duration viewers etc

Comment: @WaqarAli I would recommend changing that so 2 broadcasts do not have the same ID, it's very bad practice.

Comment: What would you recommend in this case ? What if I have structure like this :
"brodacastID"{ autoID { // broadcast detail }, autoID { // broadcast detail } }

Comment: @WaqarAli yes that's good, if you have an autoID, the broadcasts will be unique.